# regular expressions negative lookaround

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find a regular expression that matches words with "ab" but not "cd".

For example, this regex should match the following:

```
abc
dab
kab
```

It should not match the following:

```
abcd
cdab
abertcd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative look-ahead at the beginning of a word:

```
\b(?![a-z]*cd)[a-z]*ab[a-z]*\b
```

Use a case-insensitive `i` option to match capital words, too.

`\b` matches at the beginning of a word, `(?![a-z]*cd)` makes sure there is no `cd` inside a word composed of English letters. Minimal word is `ab`.

Depending on the programming language this can be further enhanced (e.g. to match Unicode letters).

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/uB1pF0/1)

Answer (score -1):

You can use (negative) [*lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to make sure that `ab` is in the string but `cd` is not:

```
^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SsL1avx5jOTC1pFN)

`^` - beginning of the string
`(?!.*cd)` - negative lookahead: do not match anything (including an empty string) that is followed by `cd`
`.*ab.*` - any string that contains ab
`$` - end of the string

Java example:

```
System.out.println("ab".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // true
System.out.println("abx".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // true
System.out.println("xab".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // true
System.out.println("cdab".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // false
System.out.println("abcd".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // false
System.out.println("abxxcd".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // false
System.out.println("cdxxab".matches("^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$")); // false
```

Python example:

```
import re
a = re.compile(r'^(?!.*cd).*ab.*$')
print a.match('abc') is not None # True
print a.match('abcd') is not None # False
print a.match('cdab') is not None # False
print a.match('ab') is not None # True
print a.match('abdc') is not None # True
print a.match('xab') is not None # True
```